# Unity crash when I try to generate rooms

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, maps, procedural-generation

I'm trying to implement the Simple Room Placement in Unity, but I have some trouble.
When I hit the Play button Unity crashes.
There is my code, the width and height are 172x80.
Thanks for the help.

```
void GenerateRoom() {
    int paddingX = 14;
    int paddingY = 14;
    roomX1 = Random.Range(0, width - paddingX);
    roomY1 = Random.Range(0, height - paddingY);

    roomX2 = Random.Range(roomX1 + 6, roomX1 + paddingX);
    roomY2 = Random.Range(roomY1 + 6, roomY1 + paddingY);

    for (int x = roomX1; x < roomX2; x++) {
        for (int y = roomY1; y < roomY2; y ++) {
            if (map[x, y] == 0) {
                GenerateRoom();
            } else {
                map[x, y] = 0; 
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Edit:
If i change my code here:

```
for (int x = roomX1; x < roomX2; x++) {
        for (int y = roomY1; y < roomY2; y ++) {
            if (map[x, y] != 0) {
                map[x,y] = 0
            }
        }
    }
```

Unity don't crash, so I presume that the problem is the recursion of the GenerateRoom() function. But in this way a room could be generate inside another room. How can I dodge that?

Comment: Are you able to provide any exception or crash details please so that we can better assist you with the issue you're having? Please [Edit your post](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/72754757/edit) to provide any additional relevant information.

Comment: Sometimes it work but often crash, you can suggest how can I get additional details?:) (I'm new with Unity)

Comment: Sure, if you take a look at the console panel in Unify after the crash (if the console is not shown, you can enable it by going to **Window** -> **General** -> **Console** [or Control+Shift+C on Windows). I'd expect there to be exceptions logged here, so if you click on the exceptions, you should see further details (including a partial stack trace) at the bottom of that panel?

Comment: When I reopen the project after the crash there is nothing in the console :/

Comment: Of course, my bad, In my head I was thinking that the Unity editor would still be running... In which case, it's worth checking out the Unity Editor log files to see if these provide any insight. The location of these logs vary depending on what OS you're on, so see [Unify Log Files](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/LogFiles.html) on where to find these.

Comment: I have found this: 
Stacktrace:
  at <unknown> <0xffffffff>
  at UnityEngine.Random.Range (int,int) [0x00001] in /home/bokken/buildslave/unity/build/Runtime/Export/Random/Random.bindings.cs:39
  <...>
  at MapGenerator.GenerateRoom () [0x00006] in /home/gregghy/SimpleRoomPlacementProceduralDungeons/Assets/MapGenerator.cs:41
  at MapGenerator.GenerateRoom () [0x00085] in /home/gregghy/SimpleRoomPlacementProceduralDungeons/Assets/MapGenerator.cs:50
  at MapGenerator.GenerateRoom () [0x00085] in /home/gregghy
The last two line returns several millions time in the log file

Comment: the end of the log file is this:
  at MapGenerator.GenerateMap () [0x00021] in /home/gregghy/SimpleRoomPlacementProceduralDungeons/Assets/MapGenerator.cs:27
  at MapGenerator.Start () [0x00000] in /home/gregghy/SimpleRoomPlacementProceduralDungeons/Assets/MapGenerator.cs:19
  at (wrapper runtime-invoke) object.runtime_invoke_void__this__ (object,intptr,intptr,intptr) [0x0002c] in <7fb66c41b6e641fb91b7fd5e48b4c50d>:0

Comment: After looking at your edit, yes, I'd say it's the recursion that's causing your issue. Your code is currently saying `if (map[x, y] == 0) { GenerateRoom() }`, but where is `map[x, y]` getting updated to somewhere other than 0? Looks like it'll try and run forever and end up causing a stack overflow

Comment: the map [x,y] is set as 1 by default. 1 mean wall, 0 mean floor. Where I want put a room I change the value of map [x, y] to 0. So the function should pick two random points in the space, and try to draw a rectangle. If this position is already a room (so map as value 0) I recall the GenerateMap function to find another place, over the function don't find a not used space.

Answer (score 0):

Basicaly if you remove all the unnecessary things your code looks like that right now. You invoke GenerateRoom multiple times each time you invoke GenerateRoom, thats a fork-bomb. Maybe change value of map[x,y] to something else before invoking it again, it will stop crashing but still your recursion is quite weird GenerateRoom would be called for each cell I would rethink that.

```
GenerateRoom()
{

    for (int x = 0; x < 100; x++) {
        for (int y = 0; y < 100; y++) {
            if(map[x,y] == 0){
                //put something like map[x,y] = 1; here?                  
                GenerateRoom();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: My fault, I have this code before:
void GenerateMap() {
        map = new int[width,height];
        FillMap();

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            GenerateRoom();
        }
    }

So I want generate 10 rooms, and if one of these touch another room I recall the function for find a new position, but after have generate 10 rooms it should stop right?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I have fix it.
How suggested by Paweł Łęgowski I have change the code for don't check every tile if it's 0. I pick the 4 side I another function and check only theses points.
Here it's the code:

```
void FindASpot() {
    int paddingX = 14;
    int paddingY = 14;
    roomX1 = Random.Range(0, width - paddingX);
    roomY1 = Random.Range(0, height - paddingY);

    roomX2 = Random.Range(roomX1 + 6, roomX1 + paddingX);
    roomY2 = Random.Range(roomY1 + 6, roomY1 + paddingY);

    bool xOK = true;
    bool yOK = true;

    for (int x = roomX1; x < roomX2; x++) {
        if (map[x,roomY1] == 0 || map[x,roomY2] == 0) {
            xOK = false;
        }
    }
    for (int y = roomY1; y < roomY2; y++) {
        if (map[roomX1,y] == 0 || map[roomX2,y] == 0) {
            yOK = false;
        }
    }
    if (xOK == true && yOK == true) {
        GenerateRoom();
    } else {
        FindASpot();
    }
}

void GenerateRoom() {
    for (int x = roomX1; x < roomX2; x++) {
            for (int y = roomY1; y < roomY2; y ++) {
                map [x, y] = 0;
            }
    }
}
```

Thanks for the help!